# Mongodb: Filtering with aggregation to get last message

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm really stuck with this problem like 6 hours ago. It's really frustrating.

This is my collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fbcd2aa0a9210007000038"),
    "from_group" : "52faa17fa0a921740c000046",
    "to_group" : "52faa173a0a921c807000037",
    "message" : "How are you?",
    "sent_time" : ISODate("2014-02-12T19:36:10.000Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fbcd39a0a921641200002c"),
    "from_group" : "52faa173a0a921c807000037",
    "to_group" : "52faa17fa0a921740c000046",
    "message" : "Fine, and you?",
    "sent_time" : ISODate("2014-02-12T19:36:25.000Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fbcd4ea0a9210007000039"),
    "from_id" : "1305426002",
    "from_group" : "52faa17fa0a921740c000046",
    "to_group" : "52faa173a0a921c807000037",
    "message" : "Fine",
    "sent_time" : ISODate("2014-02-12T19:36:46.000Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fbfa2aa0a921641200002d"),
    "from_group" : "52fbfa1ca0a921f81300002a",
    "to_group" : "52faa173a0a921c807000037",
    "message" : "Test... 1.. 2.. 3..",
    "sent_time" : ISODate("2014-02-12T22:48:10.000Z"),
}
```

This is my code:

```
    function getLastMessage($hangoutA, $hangoutB) {
        $result = $mongodb->messages->aggregate(
        ['$match' =>
            ['$or' =>
                [
                    array('from_group' => $hangoutA),
                    array('from_group' => $hangoutB),
                    array('to_group'   => $hangoutA),
                    array('to_group'   => $hangoutB),
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [ '$group' => [
            '_id' => null,
            'message' => ['$last' => '$message']
        ]
        ]);
        $message = $result;
        return $message;

}
$first = getLastMessage("52faa173a0a921c807000037", "52fbfa1ca0a921f81300002a");
$second = getLastMessage("52faa173a0a921c807000037", "52faa17fa0a921740c000046");
```

$first and $second return this:

`Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [_id] => [message] => Test... 1.. 2.. 3.. ) ) [ok] => 1 )`

The problem with $first is that the message that I expect is: "Fine".
What I expect for $second is: "Test... 1.. 2.. 3..", so that is OK.

Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I try to check all the combinations. That is a st*pid error.

To get the result that I was expected, I change this:

```
                array('from_group' => $hangoutA),
                array('from_group' => $hangoutB),
                array('to_group'   => $hangoutA),
                array('to_group'   => $hangoutB),
```

for this

```
                array('to_group'   => $hangoutA),
                array('to_group'   => $hangoutB),
```

Easy, right?

Sorry!

Comment: That is probably not what you want. The first case returns the last message considering (from_group == hangoutA) OR (from_group == hangoutB) OR (to_group == hangoutA) OR (to_group == hangoutB). What I think you want is [(from_group == hangoutA) AND (to_group == hangoutB)] OR [(from_group == hangoutB) AND (to_group == hangoutA)]

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simple query to me that doesn't need the aggregation framework. (Are you using the aggregation framework for some specific reason?)

I'm not into php so I'll use the mongo console syntax.

To find the last message sent to a group:

```
db.messages.find({"to_group" : groupID}).sort({"sent_time" : -1}).limit(1)
```

To find the last message between 2 groups:

```
db.messages.find({"$or" : [{"to_group" : groupA, "from_group" : groupB}, {"to_group" : groupB, "from_group" : groupA}]}).sort({"sent_time" : -1}).limit(1)
```